# Rinkeby ETH token address

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity

probably noob question, but I cannot find RinkebyETH token address on Rinkeby network. I would like to test approve/transferFrom with ETH, but I would need to use IERC20("token address").approve/transferFrom.

I have added Rinkeby network to MetaMask and some tokens, but I cannot find token contract address of those holding tokens in MetaMask.

Can someone point me somewhere :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ETH is the native token on Rinkeby - it has no address. Since it has no address, and no contract deployed on this address, you cannot invoke contract functions on native ETH.

However, you can use the WETH (Wrapped Ether) token instead, which is an ERC20 token meant to represent ETH and you can invoke regular ERC20 functions (including `approve()` and `transferFrom()`) on this token. There might be multiple different tokens named WETH with the same or very similar functionality deployed (and possibly controlled) by different creators. For example Uniswap publishes a link in their [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments) to this specific WETH token that they're using on Rinkeby: [0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab#code)